# Weird Internet Connection Issue

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, isp

I'm experiencing internet issues all day with the following details:

- Skype works but can't log in (login probably requires dns).
- RDP connection to a server worked normally, but pinging my public ip from the server failed.
- Dns lookup works...sometimes.
- Pinging ip always fail outside local network.
- Can search in google even if its something you've not searched for before. - - - Cannot open the results though.
- Downloads from recent downloads in chrome are normal speed.
- Android phone will not stay connected because it doesn't detect internet.

**What I have tried:**

- Rebooting router/modem
- Router claims solid internet connection but does not have any diagnostic tools.
- Router logs do not show any issues.
- Rebooting all devices (this issues exists across windows laptop and desktop and android)
- Setting dns servers to google on both router and computer
- Disabling IPV6

I connected a wireless usb stick to connect to my phone and then logged into a vpn. I then disconnected the usb stick. I can now do everything except ping (which I think the vpn might block) through my normal wired connection, however its slower than normal especially on loading new sites.

ISP says everything looks good to them.

I live in FL and one thought was the TX flooding could be causing issues upstream but my traceroutes in the past have never gone through TX. To be clear I have not changed any router settings in the last few weeks. I double-checked all the settings though and they were correct

Any ideas on what this could be and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of confusing to me but I assume you are trying to go out to the internet from your home.

I would plug in a system directly to the modem (the modem should offer some sort of DHCP service). And try to ping 8.8.8.8 (google DNS). If that fails or times out then it's either your modem or the line from you to your ISP. I would do this from a Linux live CD too just to rule out any possible software issues with Windows.

If that checks out - then it's equipment on your end such as your router.

If you are trying to ping from the internet to your home/server - you may have to toggle some settings on your end. Usually it's disabling a firewall on the modem or there is usually a flag that says "allow WAN ping" or something.

Comment: Yeah normally I can ping my home I know the setting you mean. I did plug in directly, pinging 8.8.8.8 fails 100% as does any other ip. I know its not my hardware. I'm just wondering what I can tell the ISP to check since they say all diagnostics say things are normal.

Comment: ISP finally took responsibility... one of their servers was the problem.